# Order by condition in Yii not working

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to list values from a table in a specific order. But it's working  for some order by condition and not working for some other condition. Here is the code

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = 'courseid =:courseid AND batchid =:batchid';
$criteria->params = array(':courseid' => $courseid, ':batchid' => $batchid); //Condition
$criteria->order = 'student_rollno ASC'; //Order by student roll no
$students = Student::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: If you have a decently complex SQL query, it's best practice to keep it in SQL instead of writing it in Active Record. you can try with createCommand from this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html  reference

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = 't.courseid =:course_id AND t.batchid =:batch_id';
$criteria->params = array(':course_id' => $courseid, ':batch_id' => $batchid); //Condition
$criteria->order = 't.student_rollno ASC'; //Order by student roll no
$students = Student::model()->findAll($criteria);
```